# C# - Convert Access Mdb to Accdb - error 80040154 for starting Interop.Access.Application

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am developing a small tool in C # to convert a base mdb accdb. It must run on a windows server.

To do this I use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.dll

The problem is that when I want to launch the application :

```
accessApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
```

i have the following error :

> The class factory recovery was added to the CLSID error {73A4C9C1-D68D-11D0-98BF-00A0C90DC8D9} because of the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I saved the dll with the **Regasm** command but it the same thing.I also tried to launch in x86, x64 and any CPU.

The completed code :

```
class Program
{
    public static Access.Application accessApp { get; set; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            accessApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
            accessApp.Visible = true;
            string sourceFile = @"D:\Biwee\Bases\styzan.mdb";
            string desFile = @"D:\Biwee\Bases\database3.accdb";
            //CompactAndRepair(sourceFile, accessApp);
            accessApp.ConvertAccessProject(sourceFile, desFile, Access.AcFileFormat.acFileFormatAccess2007);
            accessApp.Quit();
        }
        catch(Exception message)
        {
            var error = message;
            Console.WriteLine("Erreur : " + message);
            Console.Read();
            if(accessApp != null)
            accessApp.Quit();
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void CompactAndRepair(string accessFile, Access.Application app)
    {
        string tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(accessFile),
                          Path.GetRandomFileName() + Path.GetExtension(accessFile));

        app.CompactRepair(accessFile, tempFile, false);
        app.Visible = false;

        FileInfo temp = new FileInfo(tempFile);
        temp.CopyTo(accessFile, true);
        temp.Delete();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

**ANSWER :**

the solution is the following one, it is necessary to use the [Access Database Engine 2010 (x86 or 64)](https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=13255) which manages the mdb and accdb.

The code is as follows:

```
object[] args = new object[2]
{
(object) SourceDbMDB,
(object) DestDbACCDB
};
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("DAO.DBEngine.120"));
instance.GetType().InvokeMember("CompactDatabase", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, (Binder)null, instance, args);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(instance);
```

I developed an application to run the conversion (open the first time as an administrator to install the engine if necessary);

Then just run the following command in cmd:

```
call "ExePath" "MdbPath"
```

https://github.com/ColvrayC/App.ConvertMdbToAccdb

Comment: Do you have the full Access application installed on the machine running this code?

Comment: I installed the Access 2007 without key knowing that in access, the conversion feature is available. Can it come from that anyway?

Comment: Yes. Only the full version of Access has the ability to use the `Access.Application` object. Even the runtime version, which can do nearly all things the normal version can, doesn't allow you to use the `Access.Application` object. Note that you can run a compact and repair with the `DAO.DBEngine.120` object, which only requires the Access Database Engine to be installed (and your current compact and repair code is invalid, as far as I can see).

Comment: ok I understand better! On the other hand it means that on every post having a small program, must be installed access, would there be a way to do without?

Comment: As said, for compact and repair (and thus also for changing that file format), you just need to have the Access Database Engine (and work with  DAO.DBEngine.120). That's free, and a lot smaller than the runtime or the application.

Comment: I look at DAO.DBEngine.120, actually I manage to read my access database in .mdb, but now to save in ACCDB should I read the complete abse is INSERT in the new database? If so, it can be extremely long! @ErikvonAsmuth

Comment: Just do a compact and repair, like you intended to do...